Laravel websocket with beyondcode library and laravel echo event is not firing or echo is not listening the event
i am working with laravel 8 and beyondcode library to work with laravel websocket and realtime chat when i am triggering an event with tinker or controller my laravel echo in the frontend not getting that event or i am not sure the event is triggering properly but i have added log information in the event when i am triggering it
in the function i am able to see it in the laravel.log
  public function broadcastOn()
    {
        Log::info(
            'Broadcasted event triggered with message: ' 
        );
        return new Channel('orders');
    }

the laravel echo is not listening my custom events but the laravel echo is listening the default event which is

{"event":"pusher:pong"}2312:13:20.399{"event":"pusher:pong"}2312:13:51.396>{"event":"pusher:pong"}2312:14:22.394{"event":"pusher:pong"}2312:14:53.407


{event: "pusher:connection_establ

this events i have mention earlier
and i can not see the event in the laravel websocket dashboard
but the dashboard is showing the laravel echo event when i am first loading the page as shown in the image
here is the code of my files
this is the event file
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class OrderShipmentStatusUpdated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        Log::info('event triggered');
        
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        Log::info('event broadcast');
       

        return new Channel('orders');
    }

this is .env file
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=local
PUSHER_APP_KEY=local
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=local
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
PUSHER_HOST=127.0.0.1
PUSHER_PORT=6001
PUSHER_SCHEME=http
MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

this is the file where i am listening the event on the client side
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    {{-- // console.log(Echo);
        // Echo.channel('webappfix')
        //     .listen('WebappFix', (e) => {
        //         console.log(e);
        //     }); --}}
    <script>
        Echo.channel("orders")
            .listen('OrderShipmentStatusUpdated', (e) => {
                console.log(e.order);
            });
    </script>

</body>


</html>

this is bootstrap.js as i am using webpack
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'], // Ensure WebSockets are enabled
});

i have tried to create different event but the issue is same
i want when i hit the event it should show in the client side

Instead of using ShouldBroadcast use ShouldBroadcastNow
Yours:
class OrderShipmentStatusUpdated implements ShouldBroadcast {...}

Try:
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;

class OrderShipmentStatusUpdated implements ShouldBroadcastNow {...}

